# Rails Strong Parameters - POST a json array + one extra root field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, strong-parameters

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I need to post an json object containing an array of objects + one extra root field. So for this code:

```
{
    "root_field": "somedata",
    "myobjects": [
        {
            "attr1": "1",
            "attr2": 2",
            "attr3": "3"
        },
        {
            "attr1": "1",
            "attr2": "2",
            "attr3": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have this as code for strong parameters, which allows all `myobjects` in but fails to pass on the `root_field`, which is important in my application.

```
def my_params
  params.require(:root_field)
  params.require(:myobjects).map do |e|
    ActionController::Parameters.new(e.to_hash).permit(:attr1,:attr2,:attr3)
  end
end
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to while list `root_field` as a scalar value, it should be

```
params.permit(:root_field)
params.permit(:myobjects => [:attr1,:attr2,:attr3])
```

Comment: But that would tolerate the absence of root_field no? I require it in my application.

Comment: Strong Parameters primary goal is to prevent unexpected parameters to be used in mass assignment. The verification of the presence of a parameter is more appropriate in the model (via validations), or in the controller if it's not a model's attribute.